# .htaccess One to Three /levels

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need of `RewriteRules` that accepted something like:

```
mysite/courses going to mysite/index.php?page=courses

mysite/courses/add going to mysite/index.php?page=courses&action=add

mysite/courses/edit/3 goint to mysite/index.php?page=courses&action=edit&id=3
```

Currently, I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|js|css)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

But, when I try mysite/courses/ that doesn't working.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I got it with this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|js|css)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```